# How can I make these function calls more efficiently as they currently don't utilize the second parameter. I have already taken the user input

Tags: c++, function, input, parameters, cin

**Line 38 and 43**
*I don't see the purpose of the second parameter in the deposit() and withdrawal() functions inside the main but I need it there to run those functions. Is there a better way to do this?  Any suggestion is appreciated.*

```
int deposit(int cBalance, int dBalance)
{
  cout << "How much would you like to deposit?" << endl;
  cin >> dBalance;
  cout << "Processing Deposit......." << endl;
  cBalance += dBalance;
  return cBalance;
}
int withdrawl(int cBalance, int wBalance)
{
  cout << "How much would you like to withdraw?" << endl;
  cin >> wBalance;
  cout << "Processing Withdrawl......." << endl;
  while (wBalance > cBalance)
  {
    cout << "NOT ENOUGH FUNDS. Try Again" << endl;
    cout << "How much would you like to withdraw?" << endl;
    cin >> wBalance;
  }
  cBalance -= wBalance;
  return cBalance;
}

int main()
{
  int depositAmount, withdrawAmount;
  string moneyActivity, confirmation;
  int currentBalance = 100;
  confirmation = "YES";

  while (confirmation == "YES" || confirmation == "yes")
  {
    cout << "Yourour current balance is: $" << currentBalance << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to deposit or withdraw money? " << endl;
    cin >> moneyActivity;
    if (moneyActivity == "deposit")
    {
      currentBalance = deposit(currentBalance, depositAmount);/*depositAmount is not needed*/
      cout << "Transaction Successful! Your Final Balance is: $ " << currentBalance << endl;
    }
    else if (moneyActivity == "withdraw")
    {
      currentBalance = withdrawl(currentBalance, withdrawAmount);/*withdrawAmount is not needed*/
      cout << "Transaction Successful! Your Final Balance is: $ " << currentBalance << endl;
    }
    cout << "Would You Like To Make More Transactions? YES/NO?" << endl;
    cin >> confirmation;
    if (confirmation != "YES" && confirmation != "Yes" && confirmation != "yes" && confirmation != "NO" && confirmation != "No" && confirmation != "no")
    {
      cout << "INVALID RESPONSE. Try Again";
      cin >> confirmation;
    }
  }
  cout << "Thank you for using this service :) " << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameters should not be parameters at all, they should be local variables inside of the functions.

Also, since you are making `main()` pass in the `currentBalance` and modify it upon return, it would be better to pass in the `currentBalance` by reference instead of by value.

Also, your main `while` loop could use some tweaking to reduce redundancy (and to fix a small logic hole that allows the user to enter `"Yes"` without actually continuing the loop).

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

bool iequals(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    return equal(a.begin(), a.end(),
                 b.begin(), b.end(),
                 [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
                     return tolower(a) == tolower(b);
                 }
              );
}

int inputNumber(const string &prompt)
{
  int number;
  cout << prompt << endl;
  while (!(cin >> number))
  {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "BAD INPUT. Try Again" << endl;
    cout << prompt << endl;
  }
  return number;
}

void deposit(int &cBalance)
{
  int amount = inputNumber("How much would you like to deposit?");
  cout << "Processing Deposit......." << endl;
  while (amount <= 0)
  {
    cout << "NO FUNDS SELECTED. Try Again" << endl;
    amount = inputNumber("How much would you like to deposit?");
  }
  cBalance += amount;
}

void withdrawl(int &cBalance)
{
  int amount = inputNumber("How much would you like to withdraw?");
  cout << "Processing Withdrawl......." << endl;
  while ((amount <= 0) || (amount > cBalance))
  {
    if (amount <= 0)
      cout << "NO FUNDS SELECTED. Try Again" << endl;
    else
      cout << "NOT ENOUGH FUNDS. Try Again" << endl;
    amount = inputNumber("How much would you like to withdraw?");
  }
  cBalance -= amount;
}

int main()
{
  int currentBalance = 100;
  string input;

  do
  {
    cout << "Your current balance is: $" << currentBalance << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to deposit or withdraw money? " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    if (iequals(input, "deposit"))
    {
      deposit(currentBalance);
      cout << "Transaction Successful! Your Final Balance is: $ " << currentBalance << endl;
    }
    else if (iequals(input, "withdraw"))
    {
      withdrawl(currentBalance);
      cout << "Transaction Successful! Your Final Balance is: $ " << currentBalance << endl;
    }

    cout << "Would You Like To Make Another Transaction? YES/NO?" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    while (!(iequals(input, "YES") || iequals(input, "NO")))
    {
      cout << "INVALID RESPONSE. Try Again";
      cout << "Would You Like To Make Another Transaction? YES/NO?" << endl;
      cin >> input;
    }
  }
  while (iequals(input, "YES"));

  cout << "Thank you for using this service :) " << endl;
}
```